# Экранировать отрезок HTML кода относитьельно родительского HTML

Tags: html, html5

Такой вопрос: на страницу из базы данных выгружаются элементы HTML, но я хочу предусмотреть то, что в базе данных HTML может быть не полным, к примеру, какой-то тег, например, `div` или `span` не закрыт по какой либо причине, допустим так:

```
<div class='wraper'><div class='col'>text</div>
```

то, что первый `div` не закрыт при выгрузке из БД может вызвать проблему с тем? что он в любом случае закроется? но уже элементом из верстки, в которую будет вставлен это кусок HTML, и, вероятней всего, элементы основной верстки могут съехать.

Можно ли каким-либо образом экранировать этот код, чтобы он отображался, но не влиял на остальной родительский HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Решение 1:**

Лучше всего прямо на сервере приводить HTML в нормальный вид.

**Решение 2:**

Но если это не подходит предлагаю другое JavaScript решение.

1. Изначально на странице этот возможно невалидный HTML вставляем в строку JavaScript.
2. После загрузки страницы вставляем этот код в какой-то скрытый `div` в самом конце страницы.
3. Потом извлекаем его посредством JavaScript `innerHTML` (или `outerHTML` по желанию), после извлечения код уже валидный.
4. Вставляем куда надо.

**Решение 2.2:**

То же самое что в 2, но вставлять сразу в нужное место а не в конец HTML. Вот и рабочий код.

```js
document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = d1html;
```

```css
.cl1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hallow1
  <div id="d1">
    <script>
      var d1html = "<div class='cl1'>привет новое";
    </script>
  </div>
  <span>hallow2</span>
</div>
```

**Решение 3:**

Другое решение это вставлять код в `iframe`, разметка страницы не поедет, так как `iframe` экранирует код.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.tidy.php)

```
<?php

$html = <<<HEREDOC
<div class='wraper'><div class='col'>text</div>
HEREDOC
;

$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->ParseString($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
$html = $tidy->body();
echo $html->value;
// будет напечатано:
/*
<body>
<div class='wraper'>
<div class='col'>text</div>
</div>
</body>
*/
```

Comment: Как сильно упадёт производительность WEB-сервера при таком подходе (разумеется если страниц будет много)?

Comment: 60-80 мс если взять эту страницу